# Cannot deploy my web application to remote location through MS build. This error comes up everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am working on a big enterprise environment. When i try to deploy my solution to remote sever using ms build i get this error every time i try to deploy the app.

According to the error message it says it cannot connect but i can ping to the ip. I have even added the host ip and names in both machines host files. I don't know if i am doing anything wrong has anyone come across this before.How did you overcome this?

Note: i have replaced my ip with myip.com... and site name as my site name in this question.(My app is Asp.net MVC 4 Application)

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets  (3847): Web   deployment task failed.(Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://myip.com/msdeploy.axd?site=my site name'.) This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server. Error details: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://myip.com/msdeploy.axd?site=my site name'. Unable to connect to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond myip.com`

Any help will really be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue with IIS it was not allowing remote connections. fixed it by allowing remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

The real error message is buried in the report, but it reads:

> "Unable to connect to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond myip.com"

This is a TCP connection problem, which means there's probably a simple solution.

It should be straightforward: it means the server you've specified is not operational. If you're certain that your website is currently working (i.e. you can get to it from your web-browser) then it means you've mistyped the server's name or other connection details. It does not mean that `msdeploy.axd` is having problems because if it were, your client would at least be able to connect.

Check your server's firewall rules, and also ensure that the web server (IIS) is running and is actively listening on the IP address you want (check the site bindings and also the server's network configuration, a dump of `ipconfig /all` would also be useful).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer my server is working fine i have deployed another project the same way. Which i can get access from every machine in the network. All other projects were WCF services but this is ASP.NET MVC 4 which is trying to get deployed to IIS. I doubt some IIS configs.Can they be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the firewall setting of the host machine. Turning off firewall for local network fixed the problem